# Multiple GET key's & value's

Tags: php, get

Have searched around on google for nearly a week now to try & find an answer to this & so far I am not having much luck. Maybe I am not asking the right question.

What I am trying to do is get a single PHP script to test for both multiple keys & values from  the url entered & provide the content/function that's needed. Without having to use multiple files to get the job done.

My initial thought was to use $_GET to process the information, I came unstuck when the script would only work with the first key.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['key1'])){
   $key1 = $_GET['key1'];
   echo "Key 1 is - " .$key1. " - There is no other data.";
}
elseif(isset($_GET['key2'])){
   $key2 = $_GET['key2'];
   echo "Key 2 is - " .$key2. " - There is no other data.";
}
else {
   echo "No data provided";
}
?>
```

Hopefully that above is correct as I had to write out how I remember it being, as it wouldn't work on the second key.

I then tried a different method.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['key1'],$_GET['key2'])){
   if($_GET['key1']){
      $key1 = $_GET['key1'];
      echo "Key 1 is - " .$key1. " - There is no other data.";
   }
   elseif($_GET['key2']){
      $key2 = $_GET['key2'];
      echo "Key 2 is - " .$key2. " - There is no other data.";
   }
   else {
      echo "No data provided";
   }
}
?>
```

All that did was give me an internal server error & now I am stuck.

So my question is, how can I handle both individual & multiple keys & values within the same script without requiring other keys to be included?
I am also aiming for pure PHP so that the code will run on both linux & windows servers, this means using .htaccess to do a URL rewrite isn't an option.

NOTE!: The above is just a simple sample, the actual code will be linked to functions that perform tasks & output content.

The aim is to allow url's such as
example.com/?key1=value1
example.com/?key2=value1
With each key performing a separate function

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. What's the point of it all?

Comment: you missed } of last else as well

Comment: Do you mean it should echo both `key1` and `key2` if both are present ? Then use `if($_GET['key2'])` instead of `elseif($_GET['key2'])`.

Comment: key1 & key2 will not be present at the same time as they are entire separate functions.

Comment: Then your first tried method should work. Better use just one param `$_GET['key']` and use a [`switch`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to find the appropriate case.

Comment: I agree with "air4x" use single "key" with different values and, witch between them.

Comment: The first example should just work. There must be an error somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you, but how about this?

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value) {
    if(!empty($value)) {
        switch($key) {
            case 'key1':
                // do stuff for key1
                break;
            case 'key2':
                // do stuff for key1
                break;
        }
    } else {
        // handle if key is not set
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly what you want is:

```
if(isset($_GET['key1']) && isset($_GET['key2'])){
    //both keys are set
} elseif(isset($_GET['key1'])) {
    //only key1 is set
} elseif(isset($_GET['key2'])){
    //only key2 is set
} else {
    //no valid combinations found
}
```

Make note of the order of the statements, descending specificity, as if you had:

```
if(isset($_GET['key1'])) {
    //only key1 is set
} elseif(isset($_GET['key2'])){
    //only key2 is set
} elseif(isset($_GET['key1']) && isset($_GET['key2'])){
    //both keys are set
} else {
    //no valid combinations found
}
```

The condition for both keys being set would never be triggered as it would match on the first condition.

Comment: `isset($_GET['key1']) && isset($_GET['key2'])` == `isset($_GET['key1'], $_GET['key2'])`

Comment: You are correct, I thought it only accepts one parameter, Have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this function:

```
extract( $_REQUEST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'f' );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php